# DIY Cat6 cables only giving 100Mbps instead of 1Gbps

Tags: networking, ethernet, cable, gigabit-ethernet, cabling

I've made my own ethernet runs in the past and they've always worked great. I needed to make some more so I got some cable, some RJ45 connectors and a crimper. No matter what I do I can't get the cables to give me 1Gbps. I've tried re-crimping the ends, I've checked the length (about 3.5m well under the limits) I bought some new connectors incase the first ones weren't making good contact, no change. I've verified that the test devices can do 1Gbps by using my old cables. The only variable I can think of now is the cable itself, but I'd like to avoid buying a whole new reel if I can.

The cable I've got is marked: `Cat6 UTP SOLID 23AWG/4PRS 550MHZ TIA/EIA-568-C.2 ROHS ISO9001 143m`

According to everything I've found online this cable should be sufficient for 1Gbps.

I'm not sure what else to try, I've made cables before so I know what I'm doing when crimping and I've watched several tutorials online just to make sure I'm doing it right. The wire order I've been using is: `WO O WG BL WBL G WBR BR` which is the exact same as my other cables that all work fine.

Comment: Invest in a good ethernet cable tester. A [cheap one](https://www.amazon.co.uk/dp/B08CZW1CQ8) will tell you if the cable actually works at all, [a better one](https://www.amazon.co.uk/dp/B08CMRCDNB/ref=cm_sw_r_apan_glt_fabc_751D45P6844ANYVPK9XV) will tell you how well it will work...

Comment: I'd rather avoid the cost if I can, but that is an option

Comment: Try manually select 1Gb instead of auto negotiation.

Answer (score 1):

You almost certainly have the wrong kind of 8P8C male connectors for your cable type.

You have solid core cable, which is intended for "in-wall" runs and is intended to be terminated at a patch panel or female 8P8C receptacles like wall outlets. Solid core cable is generally not intended to have male 8P8C connectors crimped onto it.

The teeth in the typical 8P8C male crimp-on connectors are designed to pierce among the strands of stranded-core patch cable; they can't pierce into solid-core copper wire, so they don't make good, reliable contact.

It's possible to find 8P8C male crimp-on connectors that have a different tooth design, made to split around either side of solid core conductors. But since solid core cable is only meant for "in-wall" runs which aren't meant to have male connectors at either end, those special connectors are more rare and harder to find.

Comment: My connectors are apparently suitable for both solid and stranded. I've since found out that the cable isn't pure copper, it's probably plated aluminium so it's only able to sustain 1Gbs over very short distances

Comment: @OwenTourlamain It shouldn't be labeled Cat6 unless it meets all the signal integrity requirements of Cat6. If you're right that it's not meeting the Cat6 spec (regardless of what it's made of), then it was fraudulently sold as Cat6 cable. Cat6-compliant cable can handle full 1Gbps at fully 100m, and full 10Gbps at fully 40m. Maybe you can get your money back.

Answer (score 0):

Just went through this yesterday.

On a gig service now. Cable still working couldn’t get over 100 Mbps.

Checked both ends of my 100’ run and sure enough the smallest break in 2 of the 4 twisted pairs was ever so slightly broken but still making contact.

Been this way for a year and couldn’t figure it out.

It actually has happened twice in last 10 years.

If it’s in a high traffic area, other people seem to bump and push the connections Around and after time and heat they become brittle and break.

Solution: Redid cable RJ45 cable end jacks. Now receive 540MBPS over WiFi. Problem solved!!

I don’t care if you’re a master installer low-voltage, sometimes things get bumped.

And yes if you had at least $100 cable tester you would’ve got your answer instantly.